# On running the code it's only showing 4 columns instead of 8...I'm pretty sure the code is correct, why is this happening?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
patient={'patientno':[2000,2010,2022,2024,2100,2330,2345,2479,2526,2556,2567,2768,2897,2999,3000],
         'patientname':['Ramlal Tukkaram','Jethalal Gada','Karen Smith','Phoebe Buffet','Lily Aldrin','Sugmadi Kplese','Chad Broman','Babu Rao','Barney Stinson', 'Leegma Bawles','Ted Bundy','Pediphilee Kyler','Regina George','Mikasa Ackerman','Levi Ackerman'],
         'age':[22,45,17,32,32,42,45,42,31,22,35,34,17,19,36],
         'roomno':[20,60,48,13,12,69,32,40,21,63,1,54,12,68,14],
         'contactdetails':[4934944909,7685948576,5343258732,3846384849,2843839493,3237273888,9808909778,9089786756,7757586867,8878777999,7687677756,8789675758,7766969866,9078787867,6656565658],
         'diagnosis':['Dementia','Schizophenia','Intellectual Disability','Hepatitis','Child Birth','Piles','Diarrhoea','Corona','Gonorrhea','Cardiac Arrest','Psychopathy','Freak Accident','Road Accident','Attachment Issues','Depression’ ,’OCD'],
         'admitdate':['12.01.2022','13.01.2022','17.01.2022','04.01.2022','17.01.2022','12.01.2022','04.01.2022','15.01.2022','05.01.2022','13.01.2022','08.01.2022','01.01.2022','08.01.2022','10.01.2022','06.01.2022'],
         'dischargedate':['18.01.2022','17.01.2022','18.01.2022','09.01.2022','21.01.2022','15.01.2022','08.01.2022','18.01.2022','16.01.2022','17.01.2022','18.01.2022','14.01.2022','15.01.2022','13.01.2022','22.01.2022']}
df= pd.DataFrame(patient)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT

```
patientno       patientname  ...   admitdate  dischargedate
0        2000   Ramlal Tukkaram  ...  12.01.2022     18.01.2022
1        2010     Jethalal Gada  ...  13.01.2022     17.01.2022
2        2022       Karen Smith  ...  17.01.2022     18.01.2022
3        2024     Phoebe Buffet  ...  04.01.2022     09.01.2022
4        2100       Lily Aldrin  ...  17.01.2022     21.01.2022
5        2330    Sugmadi Kplese  ...  12.01.2022     15.01.2022
6        2345       Chad Broman  ...  04.01.2022     08.01.2022
7        2479          Babu Rao  ...  15.01.2022     18.01.2022
8        2526    Barney Stinson  ...  05.01.2022     16.01.2022
9        2556     Leegma Bawles  ...  13.01.2022     17.01.2022
10       2567         Ted Bundy  ...  08.01.2022     18.01.2022
11       2768  Pediphilee Kyler  ...  01.01.2022     14.01.2022
12       2897     Regina George  ...  08.01.2022     15.01.2022
13       2999   Mikasa Ackerman  ...  10.01.2022     13.01.2022
14       3000     Levi Ackerman  ...  06.01.2022     22.01.2022

[15 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Pls check out the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the limit on the number of displayed columns with:

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
```

The dataframe has 8 columns, it's just that not all are shown.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to space ( width) that you see only four columns( the first two and last two) and the rest are represented by the three dots "...". There is nothing wrong except that pandas shows partially due to spacing ( width).

Answer (score 0):

print(df) hides some columns by default.

You could either change the pandas display options mentioned by @user2314737, or you could try df.head() instead.